# java : mapping the Values from Enumeration to Object

Tags: java

**I have a Enumeration as shown in below program**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Vector v = new Vector();
        v.add("Three");
        v.add("Four");
        v.add("One");
        v.add("Two");
        Enumeration e = v.elements();

        load(e) ; // **Passing the Enumeration .** 

    }

}
```

**There is also a Student Object**

```
public Student 
{
String one ;
String two ;
String three ;
String four ;
}
```

**i need to pass this Enumeration to another  method as shown below**

```
private Data load(Enumeration rs)
 {
Student  stud = new Student();
while(rs.hasMoreElements())
{
// Is it possible to set the Values for the Student Object with appropiate values  I mean as shown below 
stud.one = One Value of Vector here 
stud.two = Two Value of Vector here 
stud.three = Three Value of Vector here 
stud.four = Four Value of Vector here 

}
}
```

Please share your ideas on this .
Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `Vector` and `Enumeration`? `ArrayList` and `Collection` are much easier to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  You could use the `elementAt` method, [documented here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#elementAt%28int%29), to get the value you wanted.  Do you have a specific reason you are using a Vector?  Some of the `List` implementations might be better.

Answer (score 0):

Enumerations don't have the idea of "first value", "second value", etc. They just have the current value. You could work around this in various ways:

1. The easy way -- convert it to something easier to work with, like to a `List`.

   ```
   List<String> inputs = Collections.list(rs);
   stud.one = inputs.get(0);
   stud.two = inputs.get(1);
   // etc.
   ```
2. Keep track of the position yourself.

   ```
   for(int i = 0; i <= 4 && rs.hasNext(); ++i) {
       // Could use a switch statement here
       if(i == 0) {
           stud.one = rs.nextElement();
       } else if(i == 1) {
           stud.two = rs.nextElement();
       } else {
           // etc.
       }
   }
   ```

I really don't recommend either of these things, for the following reasons:

- If you want your parameters in a particular order, just pass them in that way. It's much easier and it's also easier to maintain (and for other people to read).

  ```
  void example(String one, String two, String three, String four) {
      Student student = new Student();
      student.one = one;
      student.two = two;
      // etc.
  }
  ```
- You shouldn't use `Enumeration` at all, since it's been replaced with `Iterator` and `Iterable` since Java 1.2. See [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html).